# Relationship between and a Lipschitz function and a derivative of that.

Tags: lipschitz-functions

From my textbook, Measure and Integral, a function $f$ defined on $[a, b]$ is said to satisfy a ***Lipschitz condition*** on $[a, b]$ or to be a ***Lipschitz function*** on $[a, b]$, if there is a constant $C$ such that $$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\le C|x-y| \quad \text{for all } x, y \in [a, b]$$

1. a ***Lipschitz function*** is of bounded variation.
2. if $f$ has continuous derivative on $[a, b]$, then $f$ satisfies a ***Lipschitz condition*** on $[a, b]$.

---

I accepted the definition of a ***Lipschitz condition*** and understood the two theorems.

However, my professor taught us if $|f'(x)|\le C$ for all $x\in [a, b]$, then $f$ is a ***Lipschitz function***.

I do not understand how come the second theorem changes into this proposition.

Please some people tell me this?

Comment: Continuous functions are bounded on compacts.